# Is value In_array?

Tags: php, arrays

I had a php function that checked for the presence of a URL parameter in the `$old_example` array. This was all working fine, I have made some changes which modified the array (now looks like `$array`) into a multi dimensional array.

Can I not use in_array with an array like this? Any help would be appreciated, I simply need the find value function to see if tje SRID parameter is in first level of `$array`

```
$old_example = array(
 'RDfLnNCEsxxGzp6z7CUPX7OZGZqdfsGrHtfj'
);

$array = array(1) {
  ["RDfLnNCEsxxGzp6z7CUPX7OZGZqdfsGrHtfj"]=>
  array(2) {
    [0]=>
    string(9) "example1"
    [1]=>
    string(10) "example2"
  }
}
```

// Find Value Function

```
if (in_array($_GET['srid'], $array)) {
  echo "value found";
}
```

Comment: Use [`array_key_exists()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-key-exists.php) function.

Comment: Or `if (in_array(..., array_keys(...)))`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://php.net/manual/fr/function.array-keys.php

```
if (in_array($_GET['srid'], array_keys($array))) {
  echo "value found";
}
```